# Cassandra - INSERTs are not possible anymore after some time

Tags: cassandra, debian

We run cassandra 2.1.5 installation with 3 nodes on different debian wheezy VMs. Now we have the issue that after some days of operation without problems, suddenly inserts to a table are no longer possible. Then we see the following error message:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 1 replica responded)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:69)
```

When I execute nodetool status on each node, it shows me that all nodes are in Status=Up and State=Normal.

If I run nodetool repair on a node I see thousands of exceptions like:

```
2015-06-03 16:40:58,023 ERROR [AntiEntropySessions:17] RepairSession.java:303 - [repair #858c8470-09fe-11e5-930b-d16ee278cb3a] session completed with the following error
java.io.IOException: Failed during snapshot creation.
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession.failedSnapshot(RepairSession.java:344) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairJob$2.onFailure(RepairJob.java:146) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1172) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

in the log. To repair cassandra, I need to restart the cassandra daemon on every node and then run nodetool repair on every node (Which after the restart of the nodes works without throwing the exception). Then it works again for 2-3 days until the same issue appears again.

Is this a known issue or what can cause such behaviour? For me it looks like the nodes cannot talk to each other anymore when the error occurs, but if this is the case why does `nodetool status` show me UN (Up/Normal) for all nodes?